# install linux programs on chromeOS

Tags: linux, terminal, software-installation

I managed to enable Linux on my Chromebook, since it is now available as a standard in Chrome OS.

I am wondering, since now I have Linux, can I install different programs for Linux via Terminal?

I mainly have two programs:

- the first is a tar.gz file. 
  I managed to unzip it; it contains a txt file to run, but I have no idea how.
- second program is WordPress for Linux.  It is a .run; no idea either.

I guess the easiest solution would be to install Ubuntu via crouton, but I wonder if it is not necessary.

Comment: You can install these apps if they can be installed on Debian, because that is what ChromeOs uses under the hood for the Linux Apps feature. I installed Syncthing and can use it's webinterface just fine. You question would be answerable if you did provide more details about the programs you are trying to install. Many come with installation instructions.

Answer (score 0):

[Newer versions of ChromeOS](https://www.howtogeek.com/363331/how-to-set-up-and-use-linux-apps-on-chrome-os/) (69 and newer) will allow you to install some Linux apps without installing [Crouton](https://www.howtogeek.com/162120/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-on-your-chromebook-with-crouton/), but if your app has a dependency which ChromeOS does not provide, it's Crouton Time.

Since WordPress requires the stack (or combination) of Linux plus [Apache, MySQL, and PHP](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/install-wordpress-on-linux/), I am not sanguine that it will install without Crouton-Linux.

As to your other app, you will need [Developer Mode](https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/poking-around-your-chrome-os-device) enabled in ChromeOS. Other requirements may apply. See fine print in the script for details. Offer not good in Montana.